# parse facebook login background issue

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I use this code to set up the UI frame:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
[logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        // Create the sign up view controller
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
        // Present the log in view controller
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
[logInViewController.logInView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookreg.png"]]];
[logInViewController.logInView setLogo:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"joychain.png"]]];
```

[image]

why there shows 4 facebookreg.png instead of 1 on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line:

```
logInViewController.logInView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookreg.png"].CGImage;
```

Hope this works for you.